# layering background image below background color?

Tags: css

Is there a way I can layer a background color on top of the background image within the same element? Here is my CSS:

```
#pitchImg.hero{
    background:url("imgs/pitch-img.jpg") rgba(92,74,95,1);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
}
```

I've tried switching the url and rgba's places, but to no avail. Is there a method to do this other than creating another div (if such a thing exists)?

Comment: If you have a bg-color with opacity of "1" on *top* of an image, the image will not be visible, will it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can style the [:after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) pseudo element and the background color will be applied over the background image.

```
#pitchImg.hero{
    background-image:url("imgs/pitch-img.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
}

#pitchImg.hero:after {
    background-color: rgba(92,74,95,1);
    content: "";        
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3dndy89h/1/)

Comment: Ah yes! I forgot about the pseudo element. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't get it, in your jsFiddle, the color is below the image, but the contrary was asked in the question.

Comment: @YoannHercouet you can use :before or :after to change the z-index  I believe

Answer (score 0):

seperate it out: 
http://jsfiddle.net/a5vbuufb/1/

```
    #test{
    background-image: url('https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png');
    background-color: blue;
    height: 400px;
}
```

Comment: From what I'm seeing, the background image is always going to be onto of the color, no matter what order you put it in.

Comment: @Majed: The order of properties here does not matter at all – it never does in CSS. And even with multiple backgrounds, you can not have a color on top of an image – the color always has to be the last value and is therefor the lowest layer, simply because it is specified this way.